# Specify format when using concat demuxer in ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am using the concat demuxer to concatenate a bunch of audio files. The problem is that even though I know the format, the files are missing the .wav extension. Can I somehow use something like -f to tell ffmpeg the format of the files specified in the text file?

I am using a text file with something like this.

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

And this command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist -f mp3 output
```

Comment: Updated the question to explain what commands I am using. Sorry to be using the wrong forum :)

Answer (score 0):

As introduction for **concat demuxer** from [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-concat-1), there's no way you can specify demuxer.

Try **[concat filter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat)** instead.